# constraintviolationexception Campo duplicado

Tags: java, hibernate

EL error es que cuando creo un usuario con el mismo alias me salta la excepcion constraintviolationexception. He probado a realizar un try catch en el metodo del controlador pero no me lo coge y sigue saltando la excepcion

Clase Usuario

```
package com.example.demo.domain;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import com.example.demo.domain.Post;

@Entity
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String alias;

    private String contrasena;
    private String nombre;
    private String primerApellido;
    private String segundoApellido;
    private String telefono;
    private String email;
    private String sexo;
    @Column(length=5000)
    private String foto;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="PostSuyo")
    private Collection<Post> Post;

    public String getPrimerApellido() {
        return primerApellido;
    }

    public void setPrimerApellido(String primerApellido) {
        this.primerApellido = primerApellido;
    }

    public String getSegundoApellido() {
        return segundoApellido;
    }

    public void setSegundoApellido(String segundoApellido) {
        this.segundoApellido = segundoApellido;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    private Rol nombre_rol;

    public Usuario(){
        super();
    }

    public Usuario(String alias, String contrasena, String nombre, String primerApellido, String segundoApellido, String telefono, String email, String sexo, Rol nombre_rol) {
        super();
        this.alias = alias;
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.primerApellido = primerApellido;
        this.segundoApellido = segundoApellido;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.email = email;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.nombre_rol = nombre_rol;
        nombre_rol.getRol().add(this);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }

    public String getContrasena() {
        return contrasena;
    }

    public void setContrasena(String contrasena) {
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public Collection<Post> getPost() {
        return Post;
    }

    public void setPost(Collection<Post> post) {
        Post = post;
    }

    public Rol getNombre_rol() {
        return nombre_rol;
    }

    public void setNombreRol(Rol nombre_rol) {
        this.nombre_rol = nombre_rol;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(String foto) {
        if("".equals(foto)){
            this.foto = null;
        }else{
            this.foto = foto;
        }
    }
}
```

Metodo que crea al Usuario

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/registro", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registroPost(@RequestParam("alias") String alias,
        @RequestParam("contrasena") String contrasena,
        @RequestParam("nombre") String nombre,
        @RequestParam("primerApellido") String primerApellido,
        @RequestParam("segundoApellido") String segundoApellido,
        @RequestParam("telefono") String telefono,
        @RequestParam("email") String email,
        @RequestParam("sexo") String sexo,
        ModelMap m){

    try {
    Rol rolPorDefecto = (Rol) repoRol.getDefaultRol();
    Usuario u = new Usuario(alias, contrasena, nombre, primerApellido, segundoApellido, telefono, email, sexo, rolPorDefecto);
    repoUsuario.save(u);
    m.put("alias", alias);
    m.put("view","/usuario/crearPost");
    }
    catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return "views/_t/main";
}
```

Error que me aparece

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'juan' for key 'UK_js9w4v8xbocealarwch8tp0yn'
```

Comment: Cómo has puesto el try-catch? Deberías poder capturar la excepción sin problema

Comment: Yo no veo ningun `try-catch`

Comment: He actualizado el método con el try-catch ,perdonad

Comment: ¿`MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`hereda de `ConstraintViolationException `? Si no es asi nunca va a parar en el catch.

Comment: Tiene pinta de ser un problema referente a como tienes definida la tabla de MySQL, en la que se ve que tienes puesto como clave principal el nombre, y eso hace que te de un error mysql al intentar meter un valor que ya existe.

Comment: En la base de datos tengo como clave unique el alias,que es lo que quiero que no se repita @kronosXXI ¿como podria hacer para que me comprobase que el usuario existe?

Comment: Y en alias tienes siempre campos distintos?

Comment: Usa Exception y chinpom

Comment: Ya lo consegui solucionar,lo que hice fue comparar si el usuario estaba creado en la base de datos